# if a device driver is called multiple times, does the kernel create multiple processes?

Tags: process, drivers, thread

what happens if a device driver is called `open("/dev/mydrievr")` multiple times by multiple programs?

is a process created for each call?

is it possible to instantiate a thread instead of a process?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, kernel requests don’t result in new processes or threads; they are serviced in the context of the calling thread. Put another way, a system call doesn’t switch to the kernel in a scheduling sense; the kernel isn’t a separate process which is invoked when necessary. In your example, each call to `open` would be handled in the context of the calling program.

Some device drivers do need to be able to handle work outside of a process context, *e.g.* to handle interrupts which result in lengthy processing. Such drivers use [workqueues](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/workqueue.html). In the kernel, workqueues effectively use threads, but they appear as processes externally. The distinction between processes and threads in Linux doesn’t mean much in the context of kernel threads: they all share the same address space, and from a scheduling perspective processes and threads are equivalent anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of "device driver" is not quite right.

Your example open call doesn't "call a device driver", it opens a device.  In general, device drivers and devices do not create a process at all.

A device file typically corresponds to a physical hardware device and is used as a handle for a user process to access that device.  The device supports system calls (like read, write, ioctl, others) which are implemented in the device driver.  A device driver might support multiple devices each with their own device file.  No process is involved.

Part of the point of a device driver is to mediate access to the device for multiple processes and the kernel.  (The kernel might access a device directly without a user process, but through the device driver -- for instance, a disk.)